# Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present

Tags: spring, spring-orm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHHO.jpg)

I am facing an issue while trying to set up a Spring project with Hibernate for database connectivity. I am encountering the error message: "Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present," and I need assistance in resolving this issue.

Background: I am developing a Spring application with Hibernate as the ORM framework. The goal is to establish a connection to a MySQL database and perform CRUD operations.

Error Message: The error message, "Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present," is occurring during the project's execution, indicating a problem with Hibernate configuration.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you don't have HIbernate on your classpath or at least not a version supported by your version of Spring. Without knowing which dependencies you have this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you interact with classes specific to Hibernate like SessionFactory?  If not, I'd recommend just using Spring Boot Starter Data JPA and look up a basic example of how that works. Everything will be autoconfigured as far as Sessions and Entity Managers if you just create a repository interface that extends from JpaRepository.  You would just need to tell Spring where your database is and provide the username and password but all the boilerplate should be taken care of for you.